# googlemock : Legacy code classes do not inherit from abstract classes

Tags: c++, mocking, googletest

I am looking into different testing frameworks for unmanaged C++ application with VS 8.0

It looks like googlemock requires the original class to inherit from an abstract class. The abstract class is then used as a parent by google mock to generate mocks.

In my legacy code, firstly the original classes in my solution are not derived from abstract classes but non-abstract classes and there are'nt always virtual functions in them. Also, in most cases there is a chain of parents like class D is derived from Class C which is derved from Class B and so on. So to create an interface in this case will be even more involved as in mock objects all the virtual functions need to be implemented.

So I just want to know if my understanding of googlemock and test is correct and if there is a n option to not create abstract classes and simply use the existing classes as is to create mocks.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> It looks like googlemock requires the original class to inherit from
>   an abstract class. The abstract class is then used as a parent by
>   google mock to generate mocks.

No, your understanding of the `Google C++ Mocking Framework` is wrong. Inheriting of mocking class (class which you try to mock) from abstract is [design suggestion](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Alternative_to_Mocking_Concrete_Classes), but not technical requirement. The technical requirements are:

- member function which will be invoked must be a virtual (if it isn't you need use [static polymorphism](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Mocking_Nonvirtual_Methods) instead);
- member function which will be invoked must be a public;
- destructor of mocking class should be a virtual (not obligatory for trivial destructor).

Note: as you can see you don't need to worry about member function which you don't need invoke in through mock-object.

> In my legacy code, firstly the original classes in my solution are not
>   derived from abstract classes but non-abstract classes and there
>   are'nt always virtual functions in them.
>   Also, in most cases there is a chain of parents like class D is
>   derived from Class C which is derved from Class B and so on.

It is not a problem, while you don't need to invoke non-virtual member functions.

> So I just want to know if my understanding of googlemock and test is
>   correct and if there is a n option to not create abstract classes and
>   simply use the existing classes as is to create mocks.

As I said you don't need to worry about base abstract class, but anyway if your existing code doesn't satisfy the requirements you need modify it. Sometimes for someone it is unacceptable.